Cannot resolve class 'HibernatePersistence'
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.platform</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.jakartaee-api</artifactId>
        <version>10.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.persistence-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.6.4.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.ejb</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.ejb-api</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

persistence.xml
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
         version="2.0">

<persistence-unit name="sample">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <class>org.example.Book</class>

    <properties>
        <property name="dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.SQLiteDialect" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.sqlite.JDBC" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:sqlite::memory:" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="" />
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
        <property name="format_sql" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.charSet" value="UTF-8" />
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>


org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence - удалён, если хотите его использовать, нужно откатывать версии библиотек.
